# rewrite html to / page, one page over another page like example/abc/xyz/

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I have to web pages with .html extension in my website as an example are like this

example.com/abc.html
example.com/xyz.html

I want them to be like this the first page should change like this
example.com/abc/

while the second page should change like this

example.com/abc/xyz/

can that be possible?

I have done nothing as I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that is possible, just implement a rewrite rule for each endpoint:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/?$ /abc.html [END]
RewriteRule ^/?abc/xyz/?$ /xyz.html [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Wow thanks, it worked, one more question... How to redirect www to non-www and http to https . Because for SEO purpose it is a must-do thing to use one form of the website. Also if you can shed light on redirecting no existing links or pages to a 404 page.

Comment: And also I saw that example.com/abc/ is working perfectly but when I use example.com/abc  means when i don't put a trailing slash at the end it still shows that page

Comment: Redirection from http to https or www to non-www is a separate question. Please ask separate questions separate. But more important: do some research before asking. You will find _hundreds_ of existing answers here on SO for both aspects. That should be enough...

Comment: Implementing the same redirection / rewriting regardless of whether a trailing slash is specified or not is what is usually making sense. Because it follows intuition from a user point of view. If you want that different you just need to remove the last `?` inthe patterns of the rewrite rules which make the trailing slash optional.